# Save Rails Object array in Single Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables `Article` and `Master`
which table having attributes (datatype :string , data :text)

So i have to store all my Articles to Master.data So i am doing

// Array of  Article Object

```
@articles = Article.all
```

//Saving All my Article to master table

```
Master.new(:datatype=>"Article"m :data=> @articles).save
```

Its saving all the array object as String
but for future use when i am retrieving the data.

```
Master.where(:datatype=>"Article").first.data"

=> "[obj1,obj2]"
```

Its format is string 
I need as

```
Article.all
```

will it possible?
Can anyone please help me in that??

Comment: What about making an Master `has_many :articles` relationship

Comment: @Abhi can you pls add your suggestion as a answer in full explanation

Comment: @ArjunChoubey: This sound like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain what you try to achieve? Why do you need to copy all data from one table into one record of another table? What should happen if the data in `Article.all` changes? Changes the data in `Master` as well or does it keep the old state?

Comment: @spickermann I am writing a webservice Which will store list of data(1 Lakh)
And if someone is log in first time in my app then the Index webservice will call for Articles
But For next time till update is not happening it will use the data which i queried already means Master data which is storing the data of first time Listing
So that it takes very less time

Answer (score 1):

**Models**

**Master**

```
has_many :articles
```

**Article**

```
belongs_to :master
```

Now, **Article** table will have `master_id` column, that stores **Master** record's id

So, you may do:

```
@master = Master.new(attributes_for_master_table)
@master.articles.build(attributes_for_article_table)
@master.save
```

This will save **master** as well as all associated **articles** along with it.

**EDIT**

So as to answer your comment, there can be multiple reasons why it's not scalable to store all data inside a single column:

1> First of all the size of the column will be a problem over time, as it is limited to certain number (Regardless of DBMS used)

2> And by using association, you don't need to iterate through all the records. If you know the **Base** record id then, you get only associated **Slave** records to search from.

Eg: You don't have to do `Article.all` and search something. Rather you may be easily doing `@master.articles.where(condition)`

And associations possibly allows you to go to and fro, eg:

You may know the articles that belongs to a master(**@master.articles**), also you may get the master record it you have any of your article object (**@article.master**). But, with your approach knowing master record **id** is a mandate.

Comment: thanks for your reply but its same as finding the whole table itself by using 
Article.all
I have to store whole data in as single row so data if data would be large then also its take very less time.
Because querying whole data's timing is more as compared to one single row.

You can image as 100000 Data

Comment: You can always use `Master.includes(:articles).where(some_condition)` to minimize the query

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store Ruby objects directly into a database. You will have to serialize or dump that data into some string format and de-serialize that string back into an object after reading from the database.

One way to achieve that is to use a combination of `YAML.dump(@articles)` and `YAML.load(master.data)`. Another way might be the use of [Rails' serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html).

But I doubt that that will be faster than just reading `Article.all` from the other table.